# Upgrading Action-based transaction manager to support async/await

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an `Action`-based `UndoRedoTransactionManager` that looks something like this:

```
public interface IUndoRedoTransactionManager
{
    bool CanDo { get; }
    bool CanUndo { get; }
    void ClearHistory();
    bool Do(Action doAction, Action undoAction, string description);
    bool Redo();
    void RedoAll();
    bool Undo();
    void UndoAll();
}
```

which is used throughout my codebase like this:

```
var done = false;
_manager.Do(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    SomeUiWork();
    done = true;
}, () =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    UndoSomeUiWork();
    done = false;
}, "Description");
```

I am working on some new code in which I want to use my `UndoRedoTransactionManager` like this:

```
var done = false;
_manager.Do(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    SomeUiWork();
    done = true;
}, async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    UndoSomeUiWork();
    done = false;
}, "Description");
```

From what I understand, this new code creates `async void`s which should be avoided when possible. It also wouldn't guarantee that it runs without blocking.

I've read a bunch of blogs but I couldn't understand them well-enough to convert their information to my situation (I am new to async programming, and am probably doing a lot of things wrong).

My question is: **How can I expand my `Action`-based `UndoRedoTransactionManager` to also support `async/await`?** or **How can I best tackle my issue?**

I noticed that I could add a new method to my interface:

```
Task<bool> Do(Func<Task> action, Func<Task> undoAction, string description);
```

And the compiler will automatically pick this one when using `async lambda`s (and tell me to await it), however I then run into interchangeability issues.

My full `UndoRedoTransactionManager` implementation:

```
public class UndoRedoTransactionManager : IUndoRedoTransactionManager
{
    private readonly Stack<UndoRedoTransaction> _done = new Stack<UndoRedoTransaction>();
    private readonly Stack<UndoRedoTransaction> _unDone = new Stack<UndoRedoTransaction>();

    public bool CanDo => _unDone.Count > 0;
    public bool CanUndo => _done.Count > 0;

    public void ClearHistory()
    {
        _done.Clear();
        _unDone.Clear();
    }

    public bool Do(Action action, Action undoAction, string description)
    {
        var trans = new UndoRedoTransaction(action, undoAction, description);
        _unDone.Clear();
        trans.Do();
        _done.Push(trans);
        return true;
    }

    public bool Redo()
    {
        if (_unDone.Count == 0) return false;
        var act = _unDone.Pop();
        act.Do();

        _done.Push(act);
        return true;
    }

    public void RedoAll()
    {
        while (Redo())
        {
        }
    }

    public bool Undo()
    {
        if (_done.Count == 0) return false;
        var act = _done.Pop();
        act.Undo();

        _unDone.Push(act);
        return true;
    }
    public void UndoAll()
    {
        while (Undo())
        {
        }
    }

    private class UndoRedoTransaction
    {
        private readonly Action _doAction;
        private readonly Action _undoAction;

        public string Description { get; }

        public UndoRedoTransaction(Action doAction, Action undoAction, string description)
        {
            _doAction = doAction;
            _undoAction = undoAction;
            Description = description;
        }


        public void Do()
        {
            _doAction();
        }

        public void Undo()
        {
            _undoAction();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to make your whole interface asynchronous. It will be hard (maybe not possible even) to keep both sync and async versions together. Of course under the hood synchornous actions (`Action`s) will still execute synchronously, but you will still await them, because interface will be completely async. The reason is you cannot for example do `Undo()`, because you have no idea if previous action you are trying to undo is asynchronous or not.

Comment: What about converting all `Action`s to `Func<Task>`s () and making a DoAsync/UndoAsync, changing the Do and Undo to run synchronously? I'm guessing this can cause a deadlock somewhere...

Comment: Yes, that can cause deadlock somewhere, especially in UI applications where your undo manager is most useful. You might have avoided deadlock with appropriate using of `ConfigureAwait(false)`, but you are running external code provided to you by user, and you have no idea how it behaves. So doing something like `UserProvidedAsyncDelegate().Wait()` will almost certainly not end good. On the other hand, doing `await NotReallyAsyncDelegate()` will do no harm.

Comment: The only real way to get around this is to implement an asynchronous version of the `UndoRedoTransactionManager` and have a new interface that only supports async delegates? I guess that's the safest way to go about this issue.

Comment: Yes. Well you can support `async Task Do(Action, Action)`, and even `void Do(Action,Action)` if you'd like, but for most other methods they should be all async.

Comment: Which would then creep through a large amount of synchronous code, which is what I'm trying to avoid (don't have the resources to convert all that code). Making a new, asynchronous solution seems to be the safest, most time-friendly approach I can take now.

Comment: That's true, but I thought problem is you can only use one undo manager. I mean running two (sync and async) side by side makes little sense to me, since they will undo-redo different set of actions.

Comment: I'm sorry to have caused that impression. What I'm working on is a new, standalone UI that makes use of async/await throughout the code already. I wanted to reuse the UndoRedo that was already implemented for other situations, to reduce maintenance times for when/if that other code gets converted. Clearly I ended up with spending more time than it'd have taken to simply implement a new async one...